# Save address to database in gps tracking

Tags: database, google-maps, dictionary, gps, postgresql-9.1

which is suitable approach in gps tracking web application:
1)Save only latitude and longitude in database,And use reverse Geocoding for showing address of point to user in web application.
2)Save latitude and longitude with reverse geocoded address in database when  gps device send latitude and longitude to server.
But i have problem for each approach:
for first approach: When i want to show history of fleet locations to user i need to reverse geocoding many point to show addresses of any point to user that it take many time to reverse geocoding with google maps api and other problem is google maps geocoding api has limitation(2500 request per day).
for second approach:If i save address of latitude and longitude in database because every 2 minutes gps device send new point to server and saving these addresses to database can make redundancy at database! or increase database.I use postgresql DBMS and i don't know how many data can i save on the database.
How can i solve this problem?
You can see history of fleet in the following picture with populated with addresses!.But i don't know how they can implemented it!.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The amount of data in your database isn't a problem.

The best thing to do for geocoding is to do it as the data comes in.  That way, you can aggregate it if needed, and quickly show it in reports without having to repeatedly geocode.  You will need to find a geocoding provider that can handle your traffic load.  Given your needs, it might be worth buying a database of addresses and doing geocoding yourself.

Comment: PostGIS 2.0 has GeoCode functionality built in. You just need to download the TIGER dataset which takes a few hours, but it doesn't cost anything. With taher using PostgreSQL already, it just a matter adding the PostGIS extension.

Comment: PostGis GeoCode can cover Iran's data?